# Need to merge 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I need to merge 2 dataframes :

```
Siren libelleVoieEtablissement
0     one
1     two
2     three

Siren denominationUniteLegale 
0     A
1     B
3     D
4     E
```

**What I need:**

```
Siren denominationUniteLegale libelleVoieEtablissement
0     A                       one
1     B                       two
2     NaN                     three
```

**What I get:**

```
Siren denominationUniteLegale libelleVoieEtablissement
0     A                       one
1     B                       two
2     NaN                     three
3     D                       NaN
4     E                       NaN
```

I have tried inner and outer but nothing works for this case

```py
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['key'], how='left')
```

I don't want row with key=3, how to do ? I change "how" of merge to inner, outer and right but nothing is better...

Comment: where is C from ?

Comment: Please, provide your real dfs.

Comment: Thx, I updated. If you are that motivated, here are the dataframes with Siren/libelleVoieEtablissement https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/7c7e737a-0fc8-4da8-a887-155ce648e3d7 |  and with Siren/denominationUniteLegale https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/f4630f86-76e5-457f-9082-7b68351e486b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) is what you are looking for.

```
a = {'street':['one','two','three']}
b = {'name':['A','B','C','D']}

a = pd.DataFrame(a)
b = pd.DataFrame(b)
c = a.join(b)
c = c[['name','street']]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
  name street
0    A    one
1    B    two
2    C  three
```

Comment: Why did you change their input? You can't know for sure this is what they meant unless they clarify.

Comment: I think it's a relevant example. I will be happy to update my answer as soon as more details are published.